# Problem with low quality tiff

Tags: imagery, image, geotiff-tiff, generalization

I have the problem with low quality raster. Now it looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/53039057684486451032.png))</sub>

I would like to change this to looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/87768106012364755171.png))</sub>

I'm using ArcGIS, ArcScan. After some work with Photoshop and reclassify with ArcGIS I get something like that.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/35342487136630589409.png))</sub>

And after ArcScan I get:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/98057626549525851657.png))</sub>

I don't really know if I'm using ArcScan correctly or the problem is with low quality raster. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you please edit your post or tags to include which software you would like to use? If you are using ArcGIS, ArcScan may be able to tackle this.

Comment: Try to run it through PoTrace - it might be able to clean it for you ?

Comment: Can u please explain how to use PoTrace? I download it from website http://potrace.sourceforge.net/   but when i try to open .bmp raster it say " file format not recognized". Do you know why?

Comment: Unfortunately, my script didn't recognize the images as being placeholders. I can't find the originals in the Wayback Machine; do you happen to still have them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer :) I changed the parametrs in reclassify from 127,5 to 218

If you look at first picture you can see then most records have value something near 255.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/55965357082077151105.png))</sub>

But the parametr that i was looking for is 218.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/06431405368107790078.png))</sub>

Im not sure why is like that but the result is great :)

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [iv.pl](http://iv.pl/images/07339715725891677777.png))</sub>